# Are there other options then placing interfaces in seperate files when doing export = Class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
interface IClass{}
interface ITest {}

Class MyClass implements IClass
{
     test : ITest = null;


}
export = MyClass
```

Are there any way that I can get the above effect in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid not. Export creates a namespace within the file.

Comment: That's really great design!

Comment: @siride sarcasm or appreciation? I think it is good design, it maps with the nature of export in commonjs / requirejs(if done properly)

Comment: I found a somewhat decent solution. I just create the interface in seperate file and it dont mean anything for the use as its auto included when i include the above script also.  I just always do export = ---  as i hate to do the import m = require(...)  , new m.class().

Comment: This "feature" of TypeScript is really a bummer, as I have lots of cases where I would like to do exactly what the question is asking.  I put forward a feature request to allow exporting interfaces from a module which includes an "export =" statement, but I don't think it is being worked on yet. Technically there is no reason not to allow exporting interfaces since interfaces do not compile to anything in JavaScript.